# Form Layout style

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle9i, oracleforms

As we know Data Blocks style layout in oracle can view in 2 way: 
1. FORM
2. TABULAR

I want to know in Java is there any component have same behavior? I mean I want to have table(in form style) same as a data blocks that customer enter his data than after he press save all data go to database, is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike .NET, Java doesn't have a UI component which can be connected directly to a database table for editing.

I'm also not aware of a framework which adds this. There are DB tools like [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) which have inline table editing.

There are lots of frameworks to map DB tables to [Java POJOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) (Hibernate, for example) but that means you need to define Java mappings for your database tables. With that, you can use UI frameworks like [Metawidget](http://www.metawidget.org/) to create an editor.